# iOS app only pulling new data from database after reinstall of app?

Tags: ios, database, swift3

I'm working on a quiz app which pulls its data from a database using a variety of API calls. For some reason when I am trying to pull new data (we have added / deleted a quiz from the database) I get the old JSON until I uninstall and reinstall the app onto the simulator.  I am printing out the JSON that is retrieved and the phone is displaying the same quizzes that get pulled. What's weird is that if we do the request in browser, we see the updated JSON immediately after editing the database. Whats weirder is that it was working fine (updated whenever we reload the view) until today, and our leaderboard view is updating normally.  The guy working on the database swears that he hasn't changed anything yet I haven't touched the function which handles the API call in weeks. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'll put the method I'm using below.

```
func getQuizTitles() {
    let getQuizTitlesURL = URL(string: "(api_url_here)")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: getQuizTitlesURL! as URL, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        print(response as Any)
        do{
            if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSArray {
                print(parsedData)

                var title:String
                var creator:String
                var length:Int
                var quizId:Int
                let questions:[Question] = []

                for index in 0...parsedData.count-1 {
                    let aObject = parsedData[index] as! [String : AnyObject]
                    title = (aObject["Title"] as? String)!
                    if aObject["Creator"] as? String == nil {
                        creator = ""
                    }else{
                        creator = aObject["Creator"] as! String
                    }
                    //length = aObject["Length"]
                    length = 0
                    quizId = (Int((aObject["ID"] as? String)!)!)
                    let quiz:Quiz = Quiz(title: title, creator: creator, length: length, quizId: quizId , questions: questions)
                    self.quizArray.append(quiz)
                }
            }

            if let HTTPResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print(HTTPResponse)
                let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode
                if statusCode == 200 {
                    print("Success")
                }
            }
        }catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableViewOutlet.reloadData()
        }
    }).resume()

}
```

Comment: After getQuizTitlesURL variable just clear array of quizArray, something like this quizArray = []

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but didn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the app starting caching data for some reason. I added these two lines and it fixed it.

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
```

But if you are making a request, you can just add this line after you initialize the request.

```
var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: getQuestionsFromIdURL!)
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
```